# Jackrabbit in EJB 3.1 Session Bean

Tags: java, ejb-3.1, jackrabbit

Is it possible to inject a JackRabbit repository into an EJB 3.1 Session bean instead of looking it up with JNDI?

This is how it is currently being looked up

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
repository = (Repository) ctx.lookup("java:jcr/local");
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you can inject it using the @Resource annotation, like this:

```
private Repository repository;

[...]

@Resource(name="java:/jca/YourRepository")
public void setRepository(Repository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
}
```

Comment: "java:/" is not a valid name prefix for an resource environment reference, and you've not indicated how the resource environment reference is related to the "java:jcr/local" JNDI name that the OP already has.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can inject it using @Resource:

```
@Resource(lookup="java:jcr/local")
private Repository repository;
```